# list view cannot display

Tags: android, listview

I just tried to custom ListView (with checkbox) in android about "destination" information, it is very strange for me, because there is no error in Logcat but Listview doesnt display the items

I have searched the possible mistakes for a whole day, but I could figure out the real reason. Please help me! Thx!

here is my source :

code of ListView Adapter :

```
public class DestinationAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<Destination> destinationList;

private static HashMap<Integer,Boolean> isSelected;

Context context;

LayoutInflater mInflater = null;


public DestinationAdapter(List<Destination> destinationList, Context context) {

    super();
    destinationList = new ArrayList<Destination>();

    this.context = context;
    this.destinationList = destinationList;

    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    isSelected = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();


    init();
}



private void init(){
    for(int i=0; i< destinationList.size(); i++) {
        getIsSelected().put(i,false);
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return destinationList.size();
}

@Override
public Destination getItem(int position) {

    return destinationList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.destination_item, null);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();


        viewHolder.destinationImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById
                (R.id.destination_image);
        viewHolder.destinationName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById
                (R.id.destination_name);
        viewHolder.placeSelected = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById
                (R.id.place_select);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder); 
        }
    else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
        }


    viewHolder.destinationName.setText(destinationList.get(position).getName());
    viewHolder.destinationImage.setImageResource(destinationList.get(position).getImageId());
    viewHolder.placeSelected.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isSelected.get(position)) {
                isSelected.put(position, false);
                setIsSelected(isSelected);
            } else {
                isSelected.put(position, true);
                setIsSelected(isSelected);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    viewHolder.placeSelected.setChecked(getIsSelected().get(position));

    return convertView;
}


public static HashMap<Integer,Boolean> getIsSelected() {
    return isSelected;
}

public static void setIsSelected(HashMap<Integer,Boolean> isSelected) {
    DestinationAdapter.isSelected = isSelected;
}


class ViewHolder {
    ImageView destinationImage;
    TextView destinationName;
    CheckBox placeSelected;
}
```

}

and my activity(I have deleted the irrelevant parts for other display):

```
public class DestinationActivity extends Activity {

private ListView listView;


private List<Destination> destinationList = new ArrayList<Destination>();

private DestinationAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.destination_layout);


    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_destination);


    initDestinations(); 

    adapter = new DestinationAdapter(destinationList, DestinationActivity.this);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

   }


//初始化数据
private void initDestinations() {
    Destination destination1 = new Destination("beijing", R.drawable.car);
    destinationList.add(destination1);
    Destination destination2 = new Destination("shanghai", R.drawable.car);
    destinationList.add(destination2);
    Destination destination3 = new Destination("hangzhou", R.drawable.car);
    destinationList.add(destination3);
    Destination destination4 = new Destination("guangzhou", R.drawable.car);
    destinationList.add(destination4);
    Destination destination5 = new Destination("shenzhen", R.drawable.car);
    destinationList.add(destination5);
    Destination destination6 = new Destination("zhuhai", R.drawable.car);
    destinationList.add(destination6);
    Destination destination7 = new Destination("xiamen", R.drawable.car);
    destinationList.add(destination7);
    Destination destination8 = new Destination("qingdao", R.drawable.car);
    destinationList.add(destination8);
    Destination destination9 = new Destination("jinan", R.drawable.car);
    destinationList.add(destination9);
    Destination destination10 = new Destination("zhengzhou", R.drawable.car);
    destinationList.add(destination10);
}
```

}

and the Destination object:

```
public class Destination implements Serializable {

private int id;
private String name;
private int imageId;
private int priority;
private int rank;


// 经度
private double longitude;
// 纬度
private double latitute;



public Destination(double longitude, double latitute){
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.latitute = latitute;
}

public Destination(String name, int imageId){
    this.name = name;
    this.imageId = imageId;
}

public Destination(int id, String name, int priority){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.priority = priority;
}



public double getLongitude()
{
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public double getLatitute(){
    return latitute;
}

public void setLatitute(double latitute) {
    this.latitute = latitute;
}




public int getId() { return  id; }
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public int getImageId() { return imageId; }
public int getPriority(){ return priority; }
public int getRank() {return rank;}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
public void setImageId(int imageId){
    this.imageId = imageId;
}
public void setId(int id){ this.id = id; }
```

}

two layouts xml:

item_destination.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/destination_image"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/destination_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/place_select"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"   />
```

destination_layout.xml, the listview is only a part from it

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/vertical_padding"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/horizontal_padding"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/vertical_padding" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:src="@drawable/departure" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/from_place"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="From"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/vertical_padding"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/horizontal_padding"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/vertical_padding" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:src="@drawable/departure" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_destination"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp" >
</ListView>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Please help me! It makes me confused for a few days. thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove below line from adapter's constructor.

```
destinationList = new ArrayList<Destination>();
```

You are making new reference of list from inside of adapter.

```
  public DestinationAdapter(List<Destination> destinationList, Context context) {
      super();
      // Doing this you are creating new reference of passed argument. Delete it
      destinationList = new ArrayList<Destination>();
      // Here you are getting empty list due to above statement
      this.destinationList = destinationList;
  }
```